# Google sheet script about moving row to another tab using dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Here is a video of what I am trying to do.

[https://soapbox.wistia.com/videos/rVDNWFKiuW][1]

The YT video I am trying to copy is

https://youtu.be/YBd7Bv41A1Q

Here is the script he is using.

Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (r.columnStart != 3 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value == src.getName()) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(e.value);
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,3).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,3));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### It works like this just using a simple trigger.

NO Need to create an installable trigger.  I put a dataValidation in Sheet0 column 3 from a list Sheet1,Sheet2 and it works just fine.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.range.rowStart == 1 || e.value == sh.getName()) return;
  const dest = e.source.getSheetByName(e.value);
  sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,3).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,3));
  sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: So I am very new to this. Is there a video to show this?  I copied your script and pasted in script editor. added datavalidation and when I run script I get error.        https://prnt.sc/Itb6ovxZyecR

Comment: Do I have to edit the script or just copy and paste?

Comment: I will not follow links to media that are not standard SO links.  So please just write down the error if you wish my help.  I would just copy the script into the editor and edit sheets that contain validations in column3 and rows greater than one that are not on the validation list.

Comment: Execution log
6:51:20 AM Notice Execution started
6:51:20 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: It sounds like you have attempted to run the program from the script editor and that's not possible unless you supply the event object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started) to allow the script to perform the changes once you make a change on the drop down menu.

Example:

[image]

In this image I used the same script shown in the video and I added it as a trigger for the script. Note that it was added as an `OnEdit` type of trigger:

[image]